# The component must be marked 'isExposed=true' as it is being used on a Lightning page

Tags: lightning-web-components

i am trying to move a LWC component from one sandbox to another. when i am deploying the changeset i get this error

> The component must be marked 'isExposed=true' as it is being used on a
>   Lightning page.

Any idea what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the component's name.js-meta.xml file to set isExposed to true, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Example meta XML file</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>My Component</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```